# Disable quantity widget on cart page for certain products and not for product types

Tags: commerce

I am trying to disable quantity widget on edit cart page.

I can disable the quantity widget for a product type but i need to disable quantity on the basis of product ids in the cart.

Any suggestions?

Thanks